# Is it acceptable / discouraged to emphasize data in example output?

Tags: discussion

With background in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77220079/replacing-a-specific-column-with-a-declared-variable-using-awk), the poster mentions "line 4 and 9, column 3".

It would be more clear if these lines were pointed out.

Is it acceptable or discouraged to point out relevant points in data (or for that matter, code) with comments. Given that the original is not touched.

Example edit:

```
141     VALE141P        -2.36741\
142     ILEE142M        -0.978118\
143     ASNE143L        -0.65645\
144     HISE144R        137.373\           <<< line 4
145     THRE145T        -3.11502e-11\
146     SERE146G        -0.305383\
147     ASPE147L        -1.36308\
148     ARGE148R        -6.82121e-13\
149     HISE149E        0\                 <<< line 9
150     ARGE150P        -1.81996\
```

This example is of course trivial, but sometimes the data structures here are not, and comments may indicate confusion.

I have not done any changes to above post, just wondering if there are guides.

Comment: Explain everything in prose outside data/code & minimize what you put in data/code. Including, mention explicitly that the data/code has that markup.

Comment: In this particular case the OP is displaying data in those code blocks which is present in a file, IMO it is best not to confuse readers by adding comments there (It might get mistaken as the actual contents of the file). In case of code it _might_ be acceptable to point out line numbers but the need to do so might suggest that one lacks an MRE.

Comment: _This example is of course trivial, but sometimes the data structures here are not, and comments may indicate confusion._ > and sadly some data structures don't even allow comments, [e.g. JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-comments-be-used-in-json).

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε : it is true that JSON will be invalid with comments. But it's still none the less possible to write remarks if these are clearly separated from JSON. Like `"ABC":123,      # NOTICE x,y,z`

Comment: Is the entire block of data really needed?

Comment: Especially if one refers only to a few data points, repeating them may be worthwhile. Though food for thought: If only a few data points are critical, why include so much other data that highlighting is needed?

Comment: Doesn't seem like the people commenting and answering in that post have trouble understanding anything. In any case the data table has unique values for each row, it was pretty unnecessary to refer to row 4 and 9. That'll probably be true in most cases regardless of how complex a data structure is, there has to be something in there which uniquely identifies it which can be referred to. Just don't make life harder than it needs to be.

Comment: And XML doesn't allow comments within an element (e.g., for some of the attributes). A real-world example would be for [WiX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) (the installer tool, not the web site builder)

Comment: One could also break the code up with lines of normal text that references the code. I.e., `144     HISE144R        137.373`\nThe line above causes the error "Yada yada yada" to be thrown.\n`145     THRE145T        -3.11502e-11`...